# Jqueryui : Draggable inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a function that creates some div element when a user clicks on a button. I would like these elements to be draggable but I don't know how to do it. 
Here is some code :

```
function redrawEvent(listEvent){

    [...] // Create some div (".event")
    dragAndDrop();
}

function dragAndDrop() {
    $( ".event" ).draggable();
}
```

The problem is that when it's not called on $( document ).ready draggable is not recognized and I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function
```

Do someone know how to do this?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you included **Jquery** (yep, jq too) and **JqueryUI** before your custom script.

Comment: Order is important. Thank you.